# Facing problem while installing pygame on pycharm

Tags: pygame, python-3.7

**strong text**
I am trying to install the Pygame module on Pycharm but it doesn't work for me.I go to settings for this but there is no module named Pygame. Then I go to the Pycharm terminal and see the same problem.

Comment: How are you trying and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before my friend. To me, the only thing actually worked was downloading a separate .whl extension file of pygame know as wheel. Then tried to install it via cmd. You should google to find out how is possible to install files via cmd. Just find the .whl extension of pygame and simply install it ,then Enjoy yourself.